# Find the "next" highest id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am developing a web application where there are a number of very similar pages I'd like users to browse through.  The data for these "pages" is stored in a database with a unique ID as the primary key.

I'd like to have a "NEXT" button on each page that queries the database and finds out what the next highest ID is, and displays the data from that id.  My problem is that there are a couple conditions:

- Sometimes pages may be deleted or removed, meaning that there are gaps in the IDs, so I can't just do -1.
- I need to only return pages where the column 'active' == 1

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

something like this?

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > '$id' AND active = '1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

a PREV button would then need something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id < '$id' AND active = '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: TRhanks so much, seems so simple I can't believe I didn't even think to just set LIMIT to 1!  I appreciate the previous button addition as well!

Comment: you're welcome :) I had a similar problem just a few days ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
  select t.* 
    from table t
   where t.id = 
         (select min(s.id)
            from table s
           where s.active = 1
             and s.id > target);
```

Comment: well, the mysql query optimizer will choke a little on the subselect, but I guess it doesn't really matter on the scope of the problem.

Comment: @Andreas This will only return one id from the subquery, removing the need to sort however many rows you have with an id greater than your target. I really think this should be faster

Comment: Since the subselect is independent of the outer select, frankly I'd be surprised if the execution plan had it run more than once; if that's how MySQL works today, I have a 45-min dissertation for an unimaginative PhD student. In any event, for huge N, just do two different queries for O(N) total execution.

Comment: again, it depends on how the mysql optmizer handles both queries :) This would make a good benchmark scenario!

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this is an interesting solution - something I wouldn't have come up with myself.... I honestly wonder which is faster.

Comment: @Walker: You can find out which is faster by doing `SET profiling = 1`, issuing the two SELECT statements, then viewing `SHOW PROFILES`.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
   SELECT id 
    FROM pages
   WHERE id > $current_id AND active = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your scenario I think, but anyway:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id > $lastid AND active = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id < $lastid AND active = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That should give you exactly what you are looking for, the active page with the highest id lower than the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Codeignier's active record class` [CIAR](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

Then put `$this->db->select_max();` in your application for getting the maximum possible id of the rows.